# Using post title and file name as alt text?

Tags: seo, keywords, images, google-panda-algorithm, alt-attribute

There is this plugin in WordPress called "SEO Friendly Images," it replaces the `alt` text in all of the images on my site with the combined version of the file name and post title.

For example if the title of my page is "**How to Start a Car**".
And then the file name of the image is "**car-keys.png**".
The plugin will make the `alt` text of the image "**car keys How to Start a Car**".

The URL for this plugin is: http://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-image/.

It sure seems like it got some good reviews (and 1,000,000+ downloads), however would this be a good idea to use?

I don't want to mess up my site's SEO and get penalized for something like keyword stuffing, etc. by Penguin/Panda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be considered bad for SEO and your audiences and here's why:

Alt tags should be reserved for enhancing user experience, it should not be used to manipulate search results with useless keywords that are not relevant to the image. Alt tags are for people who are blind and for those who have text based browsers or just have images disabled.

Google rankings works on many factors and its completely unnecessary to inject "title of page" into an alt tag, use the alt tags for your audience. Google will put weight on relevancy. They know that a car key is useful for a car and they most likely have it tagged into searches about starting a car.

*Also...*

Google has image search function which depending on image uniqueness can drive traffic to your site. Good descriptions of images get very good rankings. A non-relevant image will quickly be outranked, since I believe that Google image search works on clicks, so more clicks the higher you go..

Answer (score 1):

This would increase the user experience for those using a text-reader for example. The question is how to start a car. The answer (in the `alt` tag) is with car keys... Obvious isn't it?

I don't see any keyword stuffing here.

Moreover the question is whether to manually update the `alt` text of hundreds of images or do it automatically... I guess it's a matter of efficiency, either to spend hours updating alt texts or spending hours to create meaningful content.

The latter would definitely increase the users experience.

However I agree with Bybe's answer: In a perfect world with limitless resources every image should have a thoroughly crafted alt text.

Comment: Heinz, welcome to Pro Webmasters.  I have edited your answer to make it fit with the site a bit more.  This is not a forum and the order of posts on a page will change as they are upvoted and downvoted, so each answer needs to stand on its own.  Mentioning other answers is fine, but not replying to them.